# Frame Independence of Inner Product on Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am trying to prove that $\langle \omega^1\wedge\dots\wedge\omega^k,\eta^1\wedge\dots\wedge\eta^k\rangle=det(
\langle(\omega^i)^\#,(\eta^j)^\#\rangle)$ is independent of the choice of frame (where these are all one forms).  I'm pretty uncertain how to do this, but here's my attempt:

Let $(\varepsilon^i)$ be an arbitrary frame dual to $(E_i)$.  We then have that the Riemannian tensor is $g=g_{ij}\varepsilon^{i}\otimes\varepsilon^{j}$ and that $(\varepsilon^i)^\#=g^{\alpha l}\varepsilon^l E_{\alpha}=g^{ii}\varepsilon^i E_i$, since $\varepsilon^i$ is a coframe.  If I can show that $det(\langle(\varepsilon^i)^\#,(\varepsilon^j)^\#\rangle)$ is independent of the choice of frame (by showing that $\langle(\varepsilon^i)^\#,(\varepsilon^j)^\#\rangle$ is independent of choice of frame), then I've proved that the general inner product is independent of the choice of frame.

However, I end up with: $\langle (\varepsilon^i)^\#,(\varepsilon^j)^\#\rangle=g_{ij}\varepsilon^i(g^{ii}\varepsilon^i E_{i})\varepsilon^j(g^{j} \varepsilon^j E_{j})=g_{ij}g^{ii}\varepsilon^ig^{jj}\varepsilon^j=\varepsilon^ig^{jj}\varepsilon^j$, which is not (at least not obviously) independent of the choice of frame... I'm sure there's something wrong with my use of the raising operator, but at this point I'm stuck and frustrated and would appreciate any insight

Comment: What do you mean by "independent of the choice of frame"? There is no frame involved in your expressions.

Comment: @levap all the inner products are with respect to the Riemannian metric, and it is the goal of the problem to show that these inner products are independent of the choice of frame

Comment: What is your definition of a Riemannian metric? Usually, a Riemannian metric is defined as a (smooth) choice of an inner product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_p$ on each tangent space $T_p M$ and then the expression $\left< v, w \right>_p$ with $v,w \in T_p M$ makes sense without any choice of frame.

Comment: OK! You haven't added the hint and without the hint, the independence doesn't make sense. The problem asks you to show that there exists a **unique** inner product on $\Lambda^k(T_p^{*} M)$ that satisfies the formula above. You can do two things: show that such an inner product is determined uniquely by the formula, then define the inner product using the formula above and make sure that it is well-defined and gives you an inner product. Alternatively, like the hint suggests, you can choose a good basis and use it to define an inner product (by declaring the basis to be orthonormal).

Comment: Then, you must show the inner product you defined satisfies the formula. Now, a priori, a different choice of good bases would give you possible different inner products that satisfies the formula. Since you are asked to show uniqueness, you need to show that in fact your construction is independent of the basis. You can skip the independence of basis if you show independently that if such an inner product exists, it is determined uniquely by the formula but showing that the inner product you defined satisfies the formula will pretty much amount to showing the result is basis independent.

Comment: @levap i'm not sure what you mean by "then, you must show the inner product you defined satisfies the formula"...don't i define the inner product with that formula?  then don't i apply the inner product to basis elements and show that the inner product is independent of the choice of basis? this is what i was trying to do...

Comment: @malxmusician212: Umm ... I appreciate the reference to my book. But the Dropbox link you posted is a copyrighted book (the copyright is owned by Springer, not by me), and it's illegal to post it on a public website without the publisher's permission.

Comment: @JackLee your books are fantastic, thanks for them.  in the age of the internet anything can be found somewhere...

Comment: @JackLee but if you have a moment, your insight in this problem would be very much appreciated...i'm not quite understanding the difference between applying this inner product to a coframe and proving its value is independent of the choice of coframe and proving that the inner product is unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem asks you to show that there exists a unique inner product on $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$ that satisfies that for all $\omega^1, \dots, \omega^k, \eta^1, \dots, \eta^k \in V^{*}$ we have

$$ \left< \omega^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega^k, \eta^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \eta^k \right> = \det \left( \left< \left( \omega^i \right)^{\sharp}, \left( \eta^j \right)^{\sharp} \right> \right). $$

This formula doesn't involve any choice of basis for $V$. Now, the point is that not very element of $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$ is of the form $\omega^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega^k$ for some $\omega^i \in V^{*}$ and, even worse, an element $u \in \Lambda^k(V^{*})$ might have infinitely many different representations as $u = \omega^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega^k$ with different $\omega^i$'s. For example,

$$ (e^1 + e^2) \wedge (e^1 - e^2) = (-2e^1) \wedge e^2 = e^1 \wedge (-2e^2) $$

are three different representations of the same element in $\Lambda^2(V^{*})$.

This discussion implies that you can't naively define an inner product by the formula because:

1. The formula doesn't cover all elements of $\Lambda^{k}(V^{*})$. This is not that bad because elements of $\Lambda^{k}(V^{*})$ are linear combinations of elements of the form $\omega^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega^k$ and since the inner product must be bilinear, the formula in fact determines how the inner product behaves on the whole of $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$. This also shows that if such an inner product exists, it is unique.
2. The more serious problem is that elements might have many different representations which might result in inconsistent results in the right hand side.

One can argue that everything is alright without choosing a basis but this will require appealing to the universal property of the exterior product and I don't remember if Lee covers it in his book. A different approach suggested by Lee is to pick a basis $e^I$ for $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$ where $e^1, \dots, e^n$ is a dual basis of an orthonormal basis for $V$. Then, every element  $\omega \in \Lambda^k(V^{*})$ has a **unique** representation $\omega = \sum a_I e^I$ and you can define an inner product on $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$ by the formula

$$ \left< \sum a_I e^I, \sum b_J e^J \right>_{(e^i)} := \sum a_I b_J \delta^{I,J}. $$

This amounts to declaring that the elements $e^I$ form an orthonormal basis of $\Lambda^k(V^{*})$ and is clearly well-defined but now it is not clear that this satisfies the property above. If you try and check the property, you might see that it will be useful to prove in advance that if you start with a different basis $f^i$ of $V^{*}$ (which is still required to be dual to an orthonormal basis of $V$) and you define an inner product the same way using $f^i$ instead, you get the same inner product ($\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_{(e^i)} = \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_{(f^i)}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I think I'll be able to solve proof now!